# Как переопределить статическое свойство при наследовании класса?

Tags: javascript, классы

Есть класс Product, имеющий статическое свойство id. Это необходимо, чтобы каждый экземпляр получал свой id (в порядке создания экземпляра). Также есть класс Raiting, который наследуется от Product. Как можно сделать так, чтобы у класса Raiting было свое статическое свойство ID, не зависящее от родительского класса?

```
class Product {
  static id = 0;
  constructor(title, price, oldPrice, url) {
    Product.id++
    this.id = Product.id;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.oldPrice = oldPrice;
    this.sale = oldPrice - price;
    this.url = url;
    this.alt = title
  }
  currency = 'руб';

}

class Raiting extends Product {
    constructor(title, price, url, raiting) {
    super(title, price, url);
    this.raiting = raiting;
  }
  starHref = 'img/icons/icons.svg#star';
}
```

Comment: Вообще, по логике, рейтинг не должен наследоваться от продукта. Это же не продукт....Вот в качестве  параметра принимать тип Product намного логичнее

Comment: class Raiting это класс, который также создает массив объектов-продуктов, но у них еще будет указываться рейтинг. так что это точно такие же продукты)

Comment: Ага, вы ещё скажите, что человек - это продукт, т.к. на соревнованиях по синхронному плаванию им тоже рейтинг могут выставлять

Comment: Рейтинг - это сущность, с помощью которой **оценивают продукты**, а не является продуктом

Comment: То, что какой-то класс оперирует теми же полями - никак не относит его к тому же типу, что и похожие классы....... это просто похожий набор полей............. опять же, как **правильно**  сделать я написал в самом первом комментарии

Comment: Здесь должно быть не наследование, а композиция, как и написал Алексей в первом комментарии. `Raiting` должен принимать на вход продукт и его позицию в этом самом рейтинге (насколько я вас понял), но никак не дублировать класс продукта.

Answer (score 2):

статические поля не наследуются. Если нужно что-то переопределить, стоит использоваться обычные методы, которые, в зависимости от реализации, могут внутри себя использовать статические методы:

```js
class Product {
  static id = 0;
  getId() {
    return ++Product.id;
  }
  constructor(title, price, oldPrice, url) {

    this.id = this.getId();
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.oldPrice = oldPrice;
    this.sale = oldPrice - price;
    this.url = url;
    this.alt = title
  }
  currency = 'руб';

}

class Raiting extends Product {
  static id = 0;
  getId() {
    return ++Raiting.id;
  }
  constructor(title, price, url, raiting) {
    super(title, price, url);
    this.raiting = raiting;
  }
  starHref = 'img/icons/icons.svg#star';
}

console.log('Product', new Product().id);
console.log('Product', new Product().id);
console.log('Raiting', new Raiting().id);
console.log('Product', new Product().id);
console.log('Raiting', new Raiting().id);
```